# How to render amp datepicker with variale year change and month change drop down

Tags: amp-html

I am having confusion with amp date picker date-format RULE

````
<amp-date-picker
    type="single"
    mode="overlay"
    layout="container"
    format="DD/MM/YYYY"
    min="12-02-2006"
    week-day-format="ddd"
    start-date="{{startdate}}"
    date="{{object.dob|date:'d/m/Y'}}"
    input-selector="[name=dob]">
  <input type="text" name="dob" class="input_form"  placeholder="Date of Birth">
</amp-date-picker>```
````

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to choose a year picker and month picker as in jquery datepicker